# How can I add elements to a LinkedList from a different class that the LinkedList is initialized in?

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I'm still relatively new to java programming. I know you use the dot (.) operator when using methods of specific classes, but I was wondering how to add elements to a LinkedList if I'm in a seperate class.

I initialize the LinkedList in a class.

Then in a seperate class's initializer, I get the information I need in order to add elements to that class. Now that I have that information
I would like to do something such as

```
listname.add(objectType object);
```

but I get a "cannot find symbol" error

For an amateur programmer like myself, it seems to be a scoping problem where it cannot see the LinkedList so I tried using a fully defined name

```
className.listname.add(objectType object);
```

But this didn't work either, If anyone has a few minutes where they could help me out with this issue I would very very much appreciate it. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You dont need objectType, just add object. You should take a java tutorial.

Comment: Unless your list is a static variable, then `className.listname` itself isn't correct, but that doesn't seem to be the major issue of learning how to pass parameters to methods

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the **list** is of type **Object**. Then, you have to do the following to add an element to the list.

```
Object obj=new Object();
listname.add(obj);
```

You have to initialize the element before adding it to the LinkedList.